# Как из массива точек создать замкнутую фигуру?

Tags: c#, unity3d, shape

Есть массив не отсортированных точек, которые визуально образуют фигуру.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В unity есть ли инструменты в которых можно создать фигуру из этих точек, заполнить ее цветом, обвести границу и задать толщину границы? Через C# код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Между точками не прямые линии. Как понять, какой формы линии должны быть?

Comment: В коробке юнити ничего такого нет. Алгоритм постраения полигонов по массиву точек называется триагуляцией. Есть готовые фреймворки.

Comment: А какие есть фреймворки? Ну я нашел готовый алгоритм триангуляции. Создал меш добавил туда вершины и треугольники. А как это все красиво вывести? Чтобы можно было создавать обводку, наложить текстуру?

Comment: @aepot
Ну вот это можно задавать через функции кривых безье. Ну то есть есть базовые точки, между ними добавляется кривая безье и получается готовый путь из множества точек. Вот имея этот путь, как проще всего вывести красивый полигон заполненный цветом?

Comment: @manking, для обводки можно использовать `LineRenderer` (Aligment для плоскости поменяй), задав ему точки контура полученного меша. Для текстурирования нужно поколдавать с `uv` координатами полученного меша. каждая `uv` точка соотвествует `vertices` вершине, если меш плоский, можно тупо проставить соответствующие координаты xy/xz. [Mesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html)